# How to increase more speed of animation

Tags: animation

I want to increase the speed of my animation more. With the blade rotating still need more natural to speed so that the blade are not visible. I tried to add motion blur. And in the graph editor Interpolation mode as linear. What else needed to make my blades to speed more. Any suggestion. Thanks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNMg5.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at the last frame of animation increase z-rotation more and press <kbd>i</kbd> and add rotation keyframe
[image]

then change FrameRate in OutputProperties tab to max in my case 60fps so, it will look more realistic, also add motion blur.

[image]

It looked more realistic with fps increased.

Try balancing fps and z-rotation so, that it will be more realistic

Comment: Thanks.. it work